# Relationship odds for conditional data and odds ratio for unconditional data

Tags: conditional-probability, paired-data, odds-ratio, mcnemar-test

I have matched paired nominal data, transmissions and non-transmissions of a risk allele M1 from parents with genotypes M1M2, M1M1, M2M2 to affected children. We can build a 2x2 contingency table and apply the McNemar test to test whether the risk allele M1 and the non-risk allele M2 are equally transmitted to affected children:

|  | Transmitted | Transmitted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Non-transmitted | M1 | M2 |
| M1 | a | b |
| M2 | c | d |

Additionally, according to Breslow and Day 1980, p166 we can also use the discordant pairs in that contingency table to get a MLE of the odds ratio (b/c). What is the full explanation of that formula for the odds ratio? What is the relationship between the b/c and the odds ratio for unconditional data?